# Spring Security : restrict other web application access

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am running spring web application in broswer. I logged in to my account and update some value using a url say `localhost:80/update/name`. On the controller side I check `principal==null` if not redirect to login page.

Now while login to this application. I open other web application page in the same browser and execute the same update url `localhost:80/update/name` through ajax call and it is updating the value. How can i avoid this security threat.

How can i make sure that Application1 update url will be executed by application1 request only? Application2 should not be allowed to execute app1's update request no matter whether it is in same browser ?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you surprised ? You are logged, thus the browser has a valid session cookie. You ask the browser to send a request to the host (be it in first window or any other window, it is the same) : it sends the request with all relevant cookies, including session cookie and if appropriate any other security cookie. The server receives a request containing a valid session cookie for a valid logged user and even if it controls IP addressed coming from same address : all is valid and it proceeds with the request.

If you have a different browser on your client machine and if you open the connection from this unrelated browser, the server should reject your request, because the browser would not present a valid cookie.

Comment: how to avoid this in the same browser as i a accessing APP1 url from APP2

Comment: Yah i know that its cos in the same browser session will be enabled till logout. But my question was how can prevent this kind accessing other application request from another application

Comment: If you want to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery, spring security 3.2 does it out of the box. It can automatically add a `_csrf` token to any form and control it on form submission. The token is randomly generated should be unknown to any other application. There are nice examples in Spring Security Reference Manual. But it was not exactly what you were describing ;-)

Comment: What do u think what kind of threat it is ? what we call to this kind of threat ?

Comment: It was not clear that the second request was a form submission or a link from a page send by another site. And normally any decent browser should reject an ajax call to a different site.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a variant of cross-site request forgery, you should enable Spring Security CSRF protection. You can [read about it in the reference manual.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using)

Even if the two applications are on the same server, they will get different CSRF tokens, which will protect your case.

Answer (score 0):

You described Cross-Site request forgery attack. Typically when POST method is used hidden token is added to prevent it. I assume You are using GET method - It is good practice to not change any state using GET method.

Comment: There's nothing cross-site about this.